# XAMPP Apache not starting - php7ts.dll?

Tags: apache, xampp

I've just installed XAMMP 7.2.2  on Vista, but am unable to start Apache. Each and every time, I get the following error message :

« Apache 2 is starting ...
htttpd.exe : Syntax error on line 532 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf : Syntax error on line 17 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf : Cannot load /xampp/php/php7ts.dll into server : The specified procedure cannot be found." »

The php7ts.dll file is where it should be.

Line 532 of httpd.conf says : « Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf" ».

And line 17 in that second file (httpd-xampp.conf) says: « LoadFile "/xampp/php/php7ts.dll" »

I have Visual C++ 2017 (x86) installed on Vista.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? I'm encountering the exact same problem on Windows Server 2008 (same build nr as Vista, all x86 executables)

Comment: Already figured it out: turns out I was using PHP 7.2.8 with Windows Server 2008 - and PHP 7.2 does NOT support Windows Server 2008 anymore. So either stick with PHP 7.0.x or upgrade server.

Answer (score 0):

I encounted the same problem.
After replacing all paths in httpd.conf,  httpd-ssl.conf,  httpd-xampp.conf with full paths like:

`ServerRoot "d:/program_files/xampp/apache"`

apache started.

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the **x86** thread-safe PHP 7.3.1 version in order to get Apache start again. Although on a Windows 64-bit machine, x64 wouldn't work with my old (32-bit) Xampp installation.